# insert symbols with "if" conditions in a php variable

Tags: php, html

I have a php file which contains the following piece of code:

```
  $risultato='
  <div class="container"> <!--container singolo cosmetico -->

      <!-- riga 1 -->
      <div class="row" id="libro">

          <div class="column"> <!-- colonna con immagine -->
              <img class="card-img" src="img/Cosmetici/'.$row["immagine_cosmetici"].'" alt=""/>
          </div>

          <div class="info column"> <!-- colonna con info --> 
              <div class="card-body">
                  <h2 class="card-title text-white text-center ml-4 mt-3 mb-3">'.$row["nome"].'</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body" id="descrizione"> <!-- lista caratteristiche (posso inserire in class ml-4 mt-3 mb-3 per adattare alla lunghezza delle caratter  -->
                  <ul id="dati-libro">
                      <li class="card-text text-white"><u>Marca:</u> '.$row["marca"].'</li>
                      <li class="card-text text-white"><u>Tipologia di prodotto:</u> '.$row["tipologia_prodotto"].'</li>
                      <li class="card-text text-white"><u>Certificazioni:</u> 

                      ';if (in_array("Biological", $array_certificazioni)) {
                        echo '
                        <img id="bio" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/3438/3438234.png" style="width:50px; heigth: 50px;"/>&ensp;';
                      }
                      if (in_array("Vegan", $array_certificazioni)) {
                        echo '
                        <img id="vegan" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/4491/4491013.png" style="width:50px; heigth: 50px;"/>&ensp;';
                      }
                      if(in_array("Nickel Tested", $array_certificazioni)) {
                        echo '
                        <img id="nickel" src="https://www.vegup.bio/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/nickel-tested-logo-e1541500088709.png" style="width:50px; heigth: 50px;"/>
                           &ensp;';
                      }
                      if (in_array("Cruelty Free", $array_certificazioni)) {
                        echo '
                        <img id="cruelty" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/4876/4876678.png" style="width:50px; heigth: 50px;"/>
                     &ensp;';
                      }';            
                                              
                      </li>
                      
                      <li class="card-text text-white"><u>PAO:</u> '.$row["pao"].' M</li>
                      <li class="card-text text-white"><u>Prezzo:</u> '.$row["prezzo"].' <i class="fas fa-euro-sign"></i></li>
                      <li class="card-text text-white"><u>Scadenza:</u> '.$row["scadenza"].'</li>
                      <li class="card-text text-white"><u>Quantità:</u> '.$row["quantita"].'</li>
                      <li class="card-text text-white"><u>Le tue note:</u> '.$row["note"].'</li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
print $risultato;
```

More specifically, I have an array that can contain a maximum of 4 elements including: Biological, Vegan, Nickel Tested, Cruelty Free. Based on the contents of the array, I would like to display icons corresponding to each element. I tried to do this via the code pasted above, but it doesn't work properly. The icons are displayed but not in the point where I have inserted the code with the various "if", and after those the code stops because I do not see what is after. How can I do? Can someone help me?

Comment: You first load html into a variable, `$risultato`, but your IF tests are using ECHO, which sends data to the browser directly. :) Instead use `$risultato .= '<img id="bio" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/3438/3438234.png" style="width:50px; heigth: 50px;"/>&ensp;';`

Comment: Excuse me, what do you mean? Because in addition to the "if" I need the html code there is before and after (contained in the variable $ result) @RiggsFolly

Comment: ah ok I understand, it works perfectly !! Thank you very much, you have been very kind @RiggsFolly

Comment: But why can't I see the final items? That is, from "pao" to "note"? @RiggsFolly

Comment: Again, that is not being placed into the `$risultato` variable, its being sent directly to the browser. Probably outside a <ul> or <ol> so the browser is ignoring it

Comment: and how can I solve in this case? @RiggsFolly

Comment: and why do the first elements preceding the icons display them correctly? @RiggsFolly

Comment: Now I understand and I solved my problem. Thanks again for your availability!